# Magento 2 stop Magento updating the SKU on duplicate

Tags: magento2, validation, sku

When I try to create a product with an SKU the same as one that already exists Magento allows the creation but changes the SKU to be xxx-1.

Is there a way to stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most inclusive way is probably to create a plugin for \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product and do a beforeSave, and then query the database for any product with that sku and if it exists fail with an error message.

In a module's etc/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product">
        <plugin name="BeforeProductSave" type="MyNamespace\MyModule\Plugin\BeforeProductSave" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Then create the plugin php in app/code/MyNamespace/MyModule/Plugin/BeforeProductSave.php

```
<?php
namespace MyNamespace\MyModule\Plugin;

class BeforeProductSave {
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $product_repo
    ){
        $this->product_repo = $product_repo;
    }

    public function beforeSave($subject,$object){
        $sku = $object->getData('sku');//this might not work but there is a way to get sku somehow
        $product = $this->product_repo->get($sku);
        if($product->getId()){
            return $object;
        }
        else {
            die("Product $sku already exists");//you can add actual magento2 error handling after you have the rest working
        }
    }
}
```

I didn't test this code it's just templated from work I've done and by memory but it should at least get you started.  You'll have to run setup:di:compile after you add this code to get it working and to test you'll have to create a product.

The nuclear option is to create a preference for the entire \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product class and exend the \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product in your preference and rewrite the save function.

Comment: I already have this. Still, it creates a duplicate product with exact same data. :(